# Create instance from class in c# via reflection

Tags: c#

Consider this code:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance<Person>();//No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

    }
}

public class Person
{
    public Person(string name = "Shahrooz") { }
}
```

When use this code: `Activator.CreateInstance<Person>();`I get this error:

> No parameterless constructor defined for this object.

Note that my constructor has default parameter:**string name = "Shahrooz"**

Why we can not create instance from a class that has constructor,despite the constructor has default value parameter?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We can not create instance from a class that has constructor because the constructor still needs one parameter, even though it is defaulted. You can get the default value, though, by calling `GetParameters()` and accessing the initial element:

```
ConstructorInfo constr = typeof(Person).GetConstructor(new[] {typeof(string)});
ParameterInfo p0 = constr.GetParameters()[0];
object defaultValue = p0.DefaultValue;
Person p = (Person)constr.Invoke(new[] {defaultValue});
// ...or using Activator
Person p = (Person)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person), defaultValue);
```

Comment: But why we can create by this code:            object o = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(Person), "Ali");

Comment: because the method requires array of objects/parameters

Comment: @ShahroozJefriㇱ You can do that because you pass the parameter explicitly. The generic version of `Create<T>` requires a parameterless constructor, which is not the same as a constructor will all its parameters defaulted to some values.